# Why is SQL not matching two strings?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

As I said in the title, I have a query that doesn't return what's expected and it isn't logical...
Here is the case :

Table A ->  id INT, value VARCHAR

Table B ->  id INT, value VARCHAR

When I run that query `SELECT value FROM A WHERE value NOT IN (SELECT value FROM B);`

I expect that query to return all values that are not in the table B, but it returns all the values.

Let's assume that A contains

1. '425415'
2. '698741'

With that query : `SELECT value FROM A WHERE value NOT IN ('698741','425415');` 
it still returns all the values without triggering the NOT IN...

Comment: You might be looking for a join.

Comment: @gargsms Why would that help?

Comment: @gargsms I'm not looking for a join I just want the values not in the other table

Comment: A join can do that too, but I'm still interested in your `NOT IN` problem. Can you try using aliases and see what happens? Did you actually try the second hard-coded example? Could you check length of values to ensure there's no whitespace problems?

Comment: @KtX2SkD I tried aliases, still the same. And yes I tried to check values and the hard coded example.. Values are identical but still doesn't match

Comment: @BoBasket4 Can you create a sample data set with your values and show us here.

Comment: Yeah, may I suggest recreating your situation in @tablevariables or #temptables, and seeing if the problem still persists. If it does, sharing that could help. If it doesn't... check collations of tables? Try `LIKE` operator? Also, please revise question's tag conflict.

Comment: I cannot reproduce it. I presume there's a subtle error in your implementation details. You may want to edit the question and share the actual SQL code.

Comment: This may be a stupid question, so apologies if it is, but the values you are searching are both valid integers, are you wanting to check the value, or the ID?

Comment: Ok I tried something and when I remove the ticks it gives me the right result... But fields are both VARCHAR

Comment: I may have found what's causing it, fields are both VARCHAR but one is 255 NULL and the other 50 NOT NULL

Comment: NULLability won't cause this problem.

Comment: Just tested on #temptables with said definitions, not causing problems for me. I'd still recommend checking collations and testing with `LIKE`.

Comment: @KtX2SkD I guess this is a problem with the database, I can't reproduces on other tables

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Also, are you using MySQL or SQL Server? You've tagged both.

Comment: @MattGibson Well I tried with both, but I'm using MySQL

Comment: @KtX2SkD You were right ! I checked length of values but not collations; It was because one of the value have a `RC` at the end !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing checklist from comment thread:

- Testing with aliases.
- Testing with `LIKE`.
- Checking lengths.
- Checking collations.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you have a NULL in the "B" table, try this:

```
SELECT A.[value]
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON A.[value] = B.[value]
WHERE B.[value] IS NULL;
```

Or if you want to keep your code just add IS NOT NULL:

```
SELECT [value] 
FROM A 
WHERE [value] NOT IN (SELECT [value] FROM B WHERE [value] IS NOT NULL);
```

[image: sample image]

Comment: I checked there is no NULL values in both tables

Comment: So can you use the LEFT JOIN method and see the result?

Comment: On my side I try `NULL` with `NOT IN` and it doesn't return all records as discussed, instead it forces the query to return no records at all.